# @PathParam = null

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Hi I've been checking lots of posts already but I havent found the problem that's happening with me. My PathParam always is null, can anyone tell me what might be the issue

Imports in interface:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
```

Interface:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/unhash/{hash}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@ResponseBody
Token decryptToken(@PathParam("hash") String token, HttpServletRequest request) throws APIException;
```

And the implementation:

```
@Override
public Token decryptToken(String token, HttpServletRequest request) throws APIException {
```

I seen nothing strange here, it's working fine for queryparams. Any ideas? I am of confuse.

Comment: Why are you mixing Spring with JAX-RS annotations? Which one are you really trying to use?

Comment: If you're trying to use JAX-RS, remove `@ResponseBody`, remove `@RequestMapping`, add `@GET` and use `@Path("/unhash/{hash}")`. If you're trying to use Spring, get rid of  `@PathParam` and use `@PathVariable`. and get rid of `@Produces`, and add `produces` in the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: Allright I'll try that, I'm indeed using spring.

Comment: I would probably get rid of all the JAX-RS dependencies if you're not going to use them, so you don't get confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are calling your service and why you are sending HttpServletRequest parameter? I implemented your scenario using Jersey without HttpServletRequest. And i called service with service/unhash/xxx. It is works fine.

```
@Path("/service")
public class MyFirstRestService implements Rest {

        @Override
        public Response decryptToken(String token) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String output="It is success-  Path Pram : "+ token;

        return Response.ok(output).build();
        }
```

Rest.class :

```
public  interface Rest {

        @GET
        @Path(value="/unhash/{hash}")
        @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

        Response decryptToken(@PathParam("hash") String token) throws Exception;

}
```

go to http://www.javawebservice.com for more information and example